# What is an evading slinky relative to all of these things?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> If a strawberry cake inequally cut facilitates a duck with a bow-tie
>   If a polyhedron is part of a ringed planet
>   If some spaceships contain an Escher figure
>   And if a blue juicer relies heavily on six pointless dice
>   What is an evading slinky relative to all of these things?

Comment: And no, I am not on drugs right now.

Comment: Maybe you should be? :-P   (no offence intended)

Comment: @Keelhaul Whatever you are on, send me some

Comment: Brilliant puzzle :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>Didn't figure every line of the riddle out, but</s> With invaluable help from @Phylyp and @gnovice, the clues are now worked out, and

I'm confident the evading slinky is something of a

> mother

to all the things.

That would be because each line describes

> relations of SE sites, identified as [their logoes](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest).
>
>  * **aviation** (cake cut inequally, thanks @Phylyp) facilitates **travel** (duck with a bow tie @gnovice got this too)
>  * **rpg** (polyhedron) is part **worldbuilding** (ringed planet)
>  * **physics** (blue juicer, thanks, @gnovice) relies heavily on **maths** (six pointless dice)
>  * **gaming** (some spaceships, for very small values of "some") contains **puzzling** (escher figure)

And therefore, the evading slinky is definitely

> the logo of Stack Overflow, the Firstest and Bestest of all the sites.

Comment: Well done, I'll let you figure out the missing ones ;)

Comment: Since you got a lot of them, I won't add an answer. But [here's where you can find the rest](https://stackexchange.com/sites#).

Comment: strawberry cake inequally cut = ROT13(nivngvba) ?

Comment: @Phylyp: Yes, the pairs actually go together when you replace them in the sentences: "If ROT13(nivngvba) facilitates ROT13(geniry)"

Comment: The spaceships refer to ROT13(nednqr) and the blue juicer is ROT13(culfvpf).

Comment: Oh, that damn juicer cannot be unseen now! :-D

Comment: I'm also wondering if I'm the only one seeing a duck with a bow-tie, and for whose who didn't: sorry, what have been seen can't be unseen! :D

Comment: @Keelhaul, That one was definitely my favourite!  I recognized the logo from the description, but with the sharp beak and all, I’m maybe gettin a little more chicken-ish vibes from it.

Comment: @Bass With the green head? It's definitely a mallard!